# Hillshade render of DEM showing unwanted lines

Tags: cycles-render-engine, subdivision-surface

I am trying to make a hillshade using a clipped DEM. While rendering the model shows lines near the edges of dem which I am unable to fix it. The model is attached here.

[image]

Comment: You use the Terms of GIS people... you might want to ask in 3D People Language here ;)
You are Working with a "Displacement map".

Comment: Sure, I will try next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your texture is smaler then the Quad. So the Areas in your Rendering that are "zero hight" get actualy [extendet by the Texture Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html). Since most of your Texure is black on the outer pixels.. this is mostly zero. Not where this streaks are.

Set your Texture Extention Method to "Clip"[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot.